# An Array is no longer an array after an AJAX Sending

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, jquery

I use the jQuery UI sortable plugin and I don't succeed to send the "order" var (an array) with AJAX. After the ajax sending "order" is not an array anymore. I would like to have a solution only for the ajax sending.

```
$("#list-cat").sortable({ 
    placeholder: 'highlight', 
    update: function() {  
    var order = $('#list-cat').sortable('serialize'); 

    $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',               
            type: "POST",
            url: "my_url.php", 
            data: { action: "edit_cat_order", id_member: "<?php echo $id_member; ?>", id_page: "<?php echo $id_page; ?>", order: order },
            success: function(data){
                    if (data.a == true){    
                        $.colorbox({ html: data.b });                                       
                    }          
            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                        alert(xhr.responseText);
            }                       
        }); 

        }
 });
```

In "my_url.php", a foreach loop doesn't recognize $_POST['order'] as an array : "Invalid argument supplied for foreach() ...". I think the problem is in the "data" line because $_POST['order'] is an array when I use :

```
$.post("my_url.php", order);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try

```
$.post("imy_url.php", {order:order});
```

EDIT

you can use `$.makeArray`

```
$.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',               
        type: "POST",
        url: "my_url.php", 
        data: { action: "edit_cat_order", id_member: "<?php echo $id_member; ?>", id_page: "<?php echo $id_page; ?>", order: $.makeArray(order)},
        success: function(data){
                if (data.a == true){    
                    $.colorbox({ html: data.b });                                       
                }          
        },
```

Comment: Hi, I would like to have a solution only for the ajax sending (it already works with $.post sending).